Shortcuts: saving photos as files?
My shortcut for doing so where I just have a block "Save Photos as files" stopped working in iOS 18. I want to save photos in the files app in any selected directory.

I got answers on other sites to recreate the save file action, the if statement also needed to be re-created as iOS 18 changed them to add multiple conditions. I just don't know why the earlier suddenly stopped working when it was working previously.
